# Laravel continue when relation is empty

Tags: php, laravel, each

I am using the following method to generate a dropdown of `descriptions` with a their corresponding `category` as the optgroup. A `Category` hasMany `Descriptions`.

So in this case my `activeDescriptions` is my relation inside my `Category` model.

```
public static function descriptions()
{
    static::active()
        ->with('activeDescriptions')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get()
        ->each(function ($category) use (&$descriptions) {
            $descriptions[$category->name] = $category->activeDescriptions->pluck('name', 'id')->sortBy('name')->toArray();
        });

    return $descriptions;
}
```

The thing is, when a category does not have any descriptions, I want to leave it out of the dropdown at all. So I was thinking about using something along the lines of:

```
->each(function ($category) use (&$descriptions) {

    if($category->doesnthave('activeDescriptions'))
    {
        continue;
    }

$descriptions[$category->name] = $category->activeDescriptions->pluck('name', 'id')->sortBy('name')->toArray();

});
```

But this isn't working, obviously, but I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this. So any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: btw, where do you generate the `$descriptions` array/collection? You reference it but doesn't says from where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a relationship exists by using

```
->has('activeDescriptions')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Yup, I answered that myself 6 minutes before you :P I just realized it too late

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer that just popped into my head, I could simply add the following to my query:

```
->has('activeDescriptions')
```

Comment: the `has()` filters the query, so in your case that'd return an empty collection if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe:

```
if (!$category->('activeDescriptions')->count()) {
    continue;
}
```

or

```
if (!count($category->('activeDescriptions')) {
    continue;
}
```

**Update**

[filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter) could be a better approach (if not going for `has` or `whereHas` in the query itself):

```
$filtered = $categories->filter(function ($category) {
    return $category->activeDescriptions->count() === 0;
});
```

Comment: Getting same error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context